# Why is this code for checking balanced parenthesis not working for the input '( } )'?

Tags: python, data-structures

This is the code:
How do I modify this further to make it work?

```
def isValid(self, s):

    stack=[]
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if(s[i]=='(' or s[i]=='{' or s[i]=='['):
            stack.append(s[i])
        else:
            if not stack:
                return False
            elif(len(stack)!=0 and (s[i]==')' and stack[-1]=='(' or s[i]=='}' and stack[-1]=='{'
                   or s[i]==']' and stack[-1]=='[')):
                stack.pop()
    if stack:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: Unrelated to question, but just one remark: you could make your code more readable by using `in`-> `if s[i] in ('(', '{', '['):`

Comment: @Mushroomator In this case even `if s[i] in '({[':` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest fix to your code is to add an

```
else:
    return False
```

after the `elif` block. You need this because if `s[i]` is one of `')'`, `'}'`, or `']'` AND `stack[-1]` is not the corresponding `'('`, `'{'`, or `'['`, then we know that there exists a nonbalanced set of parentheses, braces, or brackets in the string.

If you are interested, below, I have modified your code to something that I find more clear and readable.

`d` is a dictionary where a key is one of `')'`, `'}'`, `']'` (*closing* parenthesis, brace and bracket) with associated values `'('`, `'{'`, `'['`  (*opening* parenthesis, brace and bracket). `stack` is initially an empty list. As we iterate over characters of the string `s`,

- if the character `ch` is one of the values in the dictionary `d` (i.e. one of the opening characters), then this character is appended to `stack`;
- if the character `ch` is one of the keys in the dictionary `d` (i.e. one of the closing characters), then it must be the case that the last appended value to `stack` is the corresponding opening character; for this to be true, `stack` has to be nonempty and the last appended value to `stack`, `stack[-1]`, has to equal `d[ch]`, which is the corresponding matching opening character (e.g. if `ch` is `'}'` then `stack[-1]` has to equal `d[ch] = '{'`). If this is true, we remove the last element of the list. If `stack` is empty or `d[ch] != stack[-1]` is `True`, there exists a nonbalanced set of parentheses, braces, or brackets in the string and so we return `False`.

If we are able to iterate over the entire string without the `return False` statement being executed, we need to make sure that `stack` is empty. `stack` will be nonempty at this point if the string has opening characters but no closing characters.

Code:

```
def isValid(s):
    d = {')': '(', '}': '{', ']': '['}
    stack = []

    for ch in s:
        if ch in d.values():
            stack.append(ch)

        if ch in d:
            if stack and d[ch] == stack[-1]:
                stack.pop()
            else:
                return False

    return False if stack else True
```

Comment: @Ishwarya S Please let me know if my post answers your question!

Comment: A good short explanation of the error and a wonderful effort to show how it could be done better. Take my upvote.

Comment: Thank you @Matthias! Appreciate it.

Comment: @oda thank you so much, for putting in your efforts to answer this question. Its perfectly working now

Comment: Happy it is working! Happy coding @IshwaryaS!